# Javascript namespacing convention

Tags: javascript, namespaces

wI'm unsure which is the better namespace convention to use.

```
var App = {}; // global variable, the root of our namespace
(function() {

   App.something = function() {

   }

})();
```

or

```
(function() {

   window.App = {}; //global variable, the root of our namespace

   App.something = function() {

   }

})();
```

window.App and var App are both global variables so both conventions achieve the same outcome, but which is better?

Comment: None it's better, they're (almost) equivalent.

Comment: Well, when using `var App = {};`, you **can't** use `delete window.App` later to remove the property. But you **can** when you declare it as `window.App = {};`. But that's really a trivial reason to use one over the other

Comment: This is likely to be closed because it's opinion based.

Comment: What if you aren't running in a browser?

Comment: node.js give me an error with second block. We talking about javascript. But node.js is javascript :-)

Comment: @SLaks that's a good point. thanks.

Comment: @gustavohenke This question could help others who don't know what the difference is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that in the first variant, `App` cannot be deleted from `window`, although it's accessible as a property of the global object. In the second case, `delete window.App` works. Also, note that you should be attaching your namespace to `window`, not `Window`, as JavaScript is case-sensitive, and Window is a constructor.

Other than that, both are basically the same, there is no "better".

Comment: The uppercase on window was a mistake, but thanks for letting me know anyway. Would you say one convention is used more commonly in the js community than the other?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the second looks cleaner to me. Another common one is `var App = (function(){ /* return your object from here */ }())`